# Android Studio Gradle - JavaExec classpath configuration - Java Reflection - class access

Tags: android, reflection, gradle, classpath

Im currently working on an android project where i have to process .java-files to possibly generate another .java-files which should then be compiled and packed into the .apk-file.

Lets assume i have 2 files which will be processed by my library, FILE_A.java and FILE_B.java.

Now i need to access these files within my library via reflection, e.g. with:

```
Class.forName("com.test.entities.FILE_A"); 
Class.forName("com.test.entities.FILE_B");
```

The problem is that i'm not able to access the class files, i think because of the missing classpath configuration. Currently i use this task to call my .jar-file:

```
task (mytask, type: org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec) {
    classpath(files('libs/myjar.jar'))
    main('com.test.TestMain')
}

preBuild.dependsOn mytask
```

I found some ressources on the web, but they all don't work.

I tried to add the following to the classpath:

`sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` (main is unknown)
`android.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` (runtimeClasspath is unkown).

So how can i access the class files in my library?

Comment: ok, i figured it out...
i had to add the following to the classpath:
`classpath(files('libs/myjar.jar', 'build/intermediates/classes/debug'))`

but now i have another two questions.

how can i configure the build lifecycle so that my custom task is executed after the .class file/ the build is finished?

is it possible to get the build output directory on a less static way, like it's currently happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
task execute(dependsOn: ['compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'], type:JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.geniml.Main'
    classpath(files('build/intermediates/classes/release',"${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/platforms/' + android.compileSdkVersion + '/android.jar'}"))
}
```

android gralde is 1.5.

As to build dir, you can use `rootProject.getBuildDir()`.  But normally build dir is a convention. A static way is ok.